# URL Redirect Not working

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module

I have this specific request where in i have to cut down specific part of the URL and redirect it to another rule in IIS 7 which uses URL Redirect 2.0

The requirement is to remove /?gclid=456 from www.domain.com/special/?gclid=456

Below is the Rule which is not working. Appreciate your help!

```
<rule name="CutQueryString" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^(.*)\?(.*)$" />
   <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

IIS Url Rewrite considers the part before the question mark as the URL, so in your case `special/`, it will not match with your pattern: `^(.*)\?(.*)$` because there is no question mark in the url.

So you have to match pretty much everything and then add a condition for a querystring

```
<rule name="CutQueryString" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)/$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="[a-z]+=\d+" />
    </conditions>
</rule>
```

This rule is still very broad, it remove any querystring value-pair with a numeric value, do you really want that?